# How to add artifactory libs inside gradle?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, repository, artifactory

I need to configure artifactory inside gradle (android app).

I already put all the script below inside build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url '.../artifactory/plugins-releases'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {    
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.14"    
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-releases-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-releases'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile a lib from this artifactory, I get this error:

```
Failed to resolve: my-lib:1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin is for **publishing** into artifactory, not for using it. If you want to use it, you need to define it as repository for your build.

Comment: I already publish in artifactory (using Eclipse). I need to use this repository in my android project now. Can you give more instructions?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:repositories_tutorial

Comment: I did that but I'm still getting an error:
Error:Authentication scheme 'all'(Authentication) is not supported by protocol 'file'
But I'm sure that my username and password are correct.

When I remove my credentials, I received another error:
Failed to resolve: com.company.app:myapplication:1.0.0

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong, if you don't share the current state.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For me, it was that the maven { url "" } value needed to start with "http://". So for exmaple

```
    maven {
        url 'http://.../artifactory/plugins-releases'
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
```